# Switch on two-character string beginning with number

Tags: java, string, enums, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a piece of code that takes in a two digit hex number, e.g. "0C", and compares it to a list.

I'm using Java 6 so can't switch on a string and was initially planning on using switch on Enums but didn't realise that Enums have to start with a letter.

Is there a simple way to achieve something like the following without a whole series of "if, else if..." statements?:

```
public void code(String oc) {

switch (oc) {
    case 00:
        // do something
        break;
    case 0A:
        // do something else
        break;
    case A1:
                   ....
             }
```

Thanks,
Robert.

Comment: You shouldn't choose the appropriate type to use based on whether it's usable in a switch statement or not. Use an enum if it's an enum. Use a String if it's a String. I really don't understand the advantage of a switch over if/else if.

Comment: Ah, OK. 
Someone told me switch was more efficient than if/else for this type of thing.
If that's not the case I'll go down the if/else route.

Comment: You can use interface defining the desired function and put them in a hashmap. But you're converting hex numbers to string and then find that you'd prefer a number. Why convert ?

Comment: You're preoptimizing. That's the root of all evil. This is not where you'll have performance problems.

Comment: Switch *is* more efficient in most cases, but it's a perfect example of a "root of all evil" type of premature micro-optimization: you have no idea whether that part of the code is actually performance-relevant, yet you're willing to waste time and compromise your design to optimize it.

Comment: Before you so quickly accept, have a look at my answer. You *can* use an enum

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 6, it is not possible to do this directly.  You have to convert the String values to numbers (somehow), and then switch on the numbers.  For instance:

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(oc, 16)) {
case 0x00:
    // do something
    break;
case 0x0A:
    // do something else
    break;
case 0xA1:
    ....
}
```

The string to number conversion is relatively expensive, and probably negates the performance benefit of using a `switch` ... unless you have a large number of distinct cases.

Comment: +1 sure, but isn't it about time you got an avatar? Or are you trying to be the incognito user with the highest rep?

Comment: What makes you think that's not an avatar?  Some people are very spikey :-)

Comment: Anyhow Jonathon Leffler holds that title, and I've no chance of beating his rep.  (Not that this is a competition ... :-) )

Comment: You're only 30K behind him. Come on... You can do it! (but not if you keep getting owned like just then - he wanted an enum solution and I gave him one :D )

Comment: "You, sir, are a bounder and a cad!  I demand satisfaction!  Pistols at dawn!"  :-) :-)

Comment: LOL *now* who has egg on his face! That will teach me for sledging. Nitey nite.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `enum`, just put a letter in front, like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    X00,
    X0A,
    XA1
    // etc
}

public void code(String oc) {

    switch (MyEnum.valueOf("X" + oc)) { 
        case X00:
            // do something
            break;
        case X0A:
            // do something
            break;
        case XA1:
            // do something
            break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to *select* exactly one element for each case, you can put everything into a hashmap:

```
private final static Value DEFAULT_VALUE = ...;
private final static HashMap<Key, Value> A_MAP = new HashMap<Key, Value>();
static { // populate the map
     A_MAP.put(..., ...);
     ...
}

// query value for key:
public Value get(final Key key) {
    final Value result = A_MAP.get(key);
    return result == null ? DEFAULT_VALUE : result;
}
```

Obviously Key and Value need to be replaced with the concrete types to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map and reflection.
First initialize your map and create a single method for each case:

```
Map<String, Method> cases = new HashMap<String, Method>();

private void doSomething(param1, param2... etc) {
    // do your stuff
}

private void doSomethingElse(param1, param2... etc) {
    // do other stuff
}

cases.put("00", this.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", param1.class, param2.class, ..);
cases.put("0A", this.getClass().getMethod("doSomethingElse", param1.class, param2.class, ..);

// etc.
```

And then, when you need to use the switch:

```
cases.get(yourCase).invoke(this, param1, param2, etc.);
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use nested switches for the first and second character:

```
    char c0 = oc.charAt(0);
    char c1 = oc.charAt(1);

    switch(c0) {
    case '0':
        switch(c1) {
        case '1':
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

but this is only readable if there are only few codes to switch on.

Comment: Thanks. There are a couple of hundred to switch on so probably not appropriate but good to know regardless.